# Integrating jprofiler into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, integration, jprofiler

I can't integrate jprofiler 7 into Eclipse Indigo.
Installation and integration completed successfully. But I can't find jprofiler in the Eclipse IDE or in Eclipse preference.

No problems in starting jprofiler, but it's just missing in my Eclipse installation.

Thanks :-)

Comment: which link did you follow for installing the JProfiler?

Answer (score 6):

The "Profile" actions in eclipse are part of the eclipse infrastructure, they are not supplied by JProfiler.

I assume that the menu item Run->Profile ... does not exist in the Java perspective after you have run the integration in JProfiler (Session->IDE integrations).

In that case, you have to enable the "Profile" actions for this perspective under Window->Customize perspective by bringing the Command tab to front and selecting the "Profile" checkbox.

Comment: There is no profile menu item in the run menu. The profile option is selected in customize perspective. 
I have installed/removed eclipse/java/jprofiler. Tried to install different versions - 32bit vs. 64 bit. 

No wonder that my hair is going gray :)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this installation and configuration guide for JProfiler: http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html#1_0

The main idea is...after intergrating with JProfiler,

1. Select Window -> Customize Perspective -> choose the Command Groups Availability tab -> select the Profile checkbox and click ok.
2. Switch to the Profiling and Logging perspective by selecting Window > Open perspective > Other > Profiling and Logging.
   Click on the launch profiling button Launch profiling configuration icon and select Profile.
   In the Profile configuration dialog, double-click on Java Application. A new configuration is created and the details are shown in the right pane.