# JProfiler standalone, how to open code in Eclipse

Tags: jprofiler

I'm evaluating JProfiler 9.
I successfully install Eclipse 4.4 plugin (at least it said so) from JProfiler's standalone app. 
However I cannot do what has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965503/integrating-jprofiler-into-eclipse?s=7|2.9416). I cannot seem to find the "Profiling" perspective in my Eclipse.

That being the case, how can I view source codes in Eclipse instead of JProfiler's own viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "profiling perspective" in eclipse. Under "Window->Customize perspective" you can add the profile actions to your current perspective, so you get the profile actions in the "Run" menu.

Comment: Is it a feature that is in the current roadmap? Yourkit has it and it certainly streamline your workflow; one can certainly feel the benefit if his working intensely with the profiler.

Comment: All profiling data is shown in a separate window. The JProfiler plugin is only for starting the process.